# Adding latex to existing pdf document?

Tags: graphics, margins, import, overpic, document-size

I would like to import a pdf document and add additional code on top of the image (the pdf).
I can write over figures by the overpic package.
The problem is that I would like my compiled latex file to have the same exact document size (geometric) as the imported graphic (pdf).
Is this possible?

Comment: I do not think so -- at least not in a systematic manner. Strange request by the way.

Comment: Maybe add your image as background and then you can add whatever you want on top of it to the page?

Comment: `exact document size` = file/data size or geometric size?

Comment: if you use `standalone` then the final document size is the size of the content, which will be the size of the original pdf page if you only over-print text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But won't the text add something to the file size?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I'm assuming the OP means the page dimensions not the size of the data.

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear. I want the geometric size to be exactly the same. I want to write a program that adds latex text over existing pdf (with images stored, not text documents). which seems impossible if I cannot capture the geometric pdf document size.

Comment: Do you need this for a single page PDF or for multiple pages?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: It's not that strange of a request. I did this multiple times in order to print text on a PDF form for example.

Comment: @Martin. My comment was under the impression that the file data size is meant :). But thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `pagecommand` option with `includepdf` to overlay the document with tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \includepdf[pagecommand={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[red, opacity=0.3] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east) ;
        \end{tikzpicture}\thispagestyle{empty}}]{test.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you can show the implementation of this with an explicit example.